# C++ Anti-aliased line for beginner to SDL

Tags: c++, line, sdl, antialiasing

Original question:

> I've been asked prior to a job interview to understand how an
>   anti-aliased line is drawn in a framebuffer, using C or C++. I haven't
>   used C, and it's been a few years for me since last using C++. I am a
>   complete beginner when it comes to graphics. My C++ experience has
>   mostly been in simple command-line programs and sorting methods. The
>   company does not care if I grab the code online, they want me to
>   understand it but still have a working executable.
>
> I've used [this tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/msvsnet2010e/index.php) to set up SDL libraries in MS VC++ 2012
>   Express, and [this algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3aXiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm#Using_Wu.27s_line_algorithm_in_SDL) for the actual anti-aliasing. I have
>   a good understanding of the algorithm, though I'm currently having
>   trouble getting it to compile. I just want a line to be drawn, and
>   then I can go forward with setting the code up to the skeleton class
>   definitions I was given. This is what I have included aside from what
>   is on that page with the algorithm:
>
> ```
> #include <cmath>
> #include <math.h>
> #include "conio.h"
> #include "stdlib.h"
> #include "stdio.h"
> #include "SDL.h"
>
> const double HEIGHT = 240;
> const double WIDTH = 320;
> const double X0 = 25.6;
> const double X1 = 64.7;
> const double Y0 = 30;
> const double Y1 = 42;
>
> int round(double number)
> {
>     return number < 0.0 ? ceil(number - 0.5) : floor(number + 0.5);
> }
>
> void main()
> {
>   Uint32 pixelColor = 00000000000000000000000000000000;
>
>   SDL_Surface* myScreen = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE,WIDTH,HEIGHT,32, 0x000000FF,
> ```
>
> 0x0000FF00, 0x00FF0000, 0xFF000000);
>
> ```
>   WULinesAlpha(X0, X1, Y0, Y1,pixelColor,myScreen);
>
>   return;
> }
> ```
>
> I'm getting the following errors:
>
> Error 21  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_main
>   referenced in function _main Error    22  error LNK1120: 1 unresolved
>   externals
>
> I've seen a few code examples saying the main function has to look
>   like this:
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> {
> }
> ```
>
> Again, graphics stuff is unfamiliar to me so I know my main function
>   is likely very wrong; I'm anticipating some shaking heads. Can someone
>   explain what is happening/what I need to do?

New:

I have now replaced my main function with the following code, based on NomNomNom069's YouTube video: "C++ SDL Tutorial 2 Creating a Screen and Handling Basic Input"

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char * args[])
{
    bool running = true;
    //initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1)
    {
        running = false;
    }

    //set up screen
    SDL_Surface *screen;

    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);

    if (screen == NULL)
    {
        running = false;
    }

    SDL_Event occur;

    //main application loop
    while (running)
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(&occur);

        if (occur.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            running = false;
        }

        //drawing occurs here
        SDL_FillRect(screen, NULL, 0);
        SDL_Flip(screen);
    }

    //quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

No errors, and I get a window to pop up. Awesome.

My question now is regarding how/where to call `WuLinesAlpha`. This function calls for 4 `double`s, a `Uint32` variable, and an `SDL_Surface*`. I have my `double`s, I set the `Uint32` to `0x000000FF`, and I assume that the `SDL_Surface` I have set up as `screen` is the one passed in.

I've toyed around with where the `WuLinesAlpha` function call goes and I keep getting the black screen. I thought, as explained in the video, it would go in the loop but nothing has happened. Are there any more SDL commands I should be calling?

Answer (score 0):

Fix your `main` declaration first.  This does need to be `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.  Especially on Windows, since I believe `SDL.h` actually renames your `main` to some other name, and takes over `main` for the library itself.

Next, make sure you link against SDL properly.  In my own SDL 1.2.x based project I have these lines in my Makefile:

```
SDL_CFLAGS := $(shell sdl-config --cflags)
SDL_LFLAGS := $(shell sdl-config --libs)
```

I then later append those flags to my actual `CFLAGS` and `LFLAGS`.  Note that if you use `make` and `Makefile`s, you want to use `:=` there, otherwise `make` will invoke the `$(shell ...)` command every time it expands `$(CFLAGS)`.

I can't help you set up Microsoft's GUI products.  This tutorial, for a slightly older MSVC product (2010), looks pretty good, and may put you on the right track:  http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/msvsnet2010e/index.php

And finally, don't forget to call `SDL_Init()` at some point, preferably before you start creating surfaces.

Good luck!

Comment: I thank you for your response, but you have confused me more. Could you please give some explanations on your recommendations? "Fix your main declaration first" isn't very helpful without knowing what needs fixing.

That is the exact tutorial I used, as I stated.

Comment: Apologies. I missed the main function set up as indicated in the tutorial for the proper. I have passed this particular issue now. I now have reached another hurdle and will post that question as a response.

Comment: I tried to understand the implementation of Wu's algorithm you linked.  I have to admit, I wasn't willing to put the effort into understanding that particular implementation.

Michael Abrash gave a pretty good rundown of Wu's algorithm in his programming books (The Zen of Graphics Programming, originally, and most recently his Black Book).  Here's a PDF link to the relevant chapter: http://downloads.gamedev.net/pdf/gpbb/gpbb42.pdf

Hopefully you can bridge between how you wish to use SDL and this algorithm. I couldn't tell you what part you should study for an interview question, though.

Comment: Also... are you sure the interviewer is looking for your line draw knowledge, as opposed to your instinct to find and install an appropriately optimized library for what should be a pedestrian task?